# Ingresar datos a una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo este código PHP, puse las alertas para ver si se mandaban los datos. Sí se muestran las alertas con la información pero no llegan a la base de datos.
También anexo el código PHP del archivo `conexion.php` que llamo con el `require`.

```
<?php
require("conexion.php");

$nom = $_POST['nombreven'];
$ape = $_POST['apellido'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];

echo "<script> alert('".$nom."'); </script>";
echo "<script> alert('".$ape."'); </script>";

mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO usuarioss (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$nom', '$ape')");
?>    

<div class="modal fade" id="mostrarmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <center><h3>DATOS GUARDADOS CORRECTAMENTE</h3></center>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <center><a class="btn btn-primary" href="altaVENDEDOR.php">ACEPTAR</a></center>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**conexion.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "gvisitel";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("", $conn->error);
} else {
    printf("", $conn->character_set_name());
}

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: cuando dices que no llegan a la bd es porque llegan como null, undefined, el string vacio pero aun asi se inserta en la bd? o que literalmente no pasa al insert.

Comment: veo un $correo = $_POST['correo']; eso no está en esa tabla de la bdd? porque si es asi no lo estas insertando en la consulta y no está guardando nada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noto varias cosas que podrían estar mal en el código:

1. En tu archivo `conexion.php` defines una variable llamada `$conn`, pero más adelante utilizas `$mysqli`. ¿No debería ser `$conn`?
2. ¿El nombre de la tabla en la DB es `usuarioss`? Y esta tabla, ¿tiene los campos que intentas agregar (nombre, apellido)?
   También puede que también tengas otros campos obligatorios.
3. Si todo lo anterior no soluciona tu problema, puedes intentar con `echo mysqli_error($conn)` o `echo mysqli_error($mysqli)` para ver el último error obtenido.

Comment: Ya lo cambié por $conn pero no inserta en la base de datos, si ese es el nombre de la tabla, ese código para saber el error donde lo pondría?

Comment: Debajo de `mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO usuarioss (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$nom', '$ape')");`.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, el error estaba en el insert, ahora si los agrega pero el cuadro que puse para que diera la notificación de que se insertó correctamente no funciona, como quiera ya inserta jaja

Comment: Por lo que veo, se trata de un *modal*, ¿es posible que no se muestre porque le falta una clase CSS o una interacción con JS?

Comment: Puede ser, por que ese pedazo de código lo use de un ejemplo que tenia ahí, necesitaria buscar uno nuevo.

Comment: Haz lo siguiente: quita las clases `modal fade` y los atributos `role="dialog"` y `aria-hidden="true"` para ver si así muestra el código

Comment: Super, ya apareció ahora si, muchas gracias, amigo.

Comment: Genial. Entonces te sugiero que consideres marcar la respuesta como **aceptada** a fin de darle cierre a esta pregunta. Si tienes dudas, puedes leer [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas).

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza la variable $mysqli (no se encuentra definida) por la variable $conn, eso arreglará el problema, el primer parámetro debería de recibir la conexión de la base de datos.

Comment: Ya lo cambié, no me funciona, no inserta en la base de datos aún.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, el error estaba en el insert, ahora si los agrega pero el cuadro que puse para que diera la notificación de que se insertó correctamente no funciona.